# How do I covert an Excel Date in MMM-YYYY to datetime or strings?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

My dataframe is taken from a Excel file which formats their dates as e.g Jan 2018.

I want to change to datetime such as 01-2018 or even as a string like 01/2018.

I have two problems:

1. When attempting to convert to datetime I have an out of bound error (nanosecond)

   ```
   twoyear_df['Date'] = twoyear_df['Date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).strftime('%m/%Y'))
   ```
2. When I try to convert them into strings with this:

   ```
   twoyear_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(twoyear_df['Date'], format='%m%Y')
   ```

I get an

```
ValueError: time data 'Sep 18' does not match format '%m%Y' (match)
```

What should do? It seems like I am unable to change to datetime because of of the nanosecond problem and I am unable to change it to a string because I cannot change it datetime?

I'm not sure how to provide a dataset as an example. I'll put a sample here

```
         Date  Price   Open   High    Low Change %
0  Sep 18  2.707  2.637  2.711  2.629    2.95%
1  Aug 18  2.629  2.669  2.686  2.587   -1.68%
2  Jul 18  2.674  2.524  2.690  2.508    5.61%
3  Jun 18  2.532  2.431  2.602  2.427    3.94%
4  May 18  2.436  2.492  2.598  2.299   -2.25%
5  Apr 18  2.492  2.278  2.508  2.234    9.78%
6  Mar 18  2.270  2.254  2.366  2.197    0.53%
7  Feb 18  2.258  2.157  2.286  1.947    5.07%
8  Jan 18  2.149  1.907  2.165  1.891   13.88%
9  Dec 17  1.887  1.790  1.927  1.746    5.42%
```

I avoid use NaT as I need to do some time series analysis. I have a feeling that all the dates saved by excel has a nanosecond problem. Is there a way to bypass or just remove it entirely?

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to successfully solve my own question. Thank you for your interest. If there any better solutions I am all ears

```
twoyear_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(twoyear_df['Date'], format='%b %y')
```